# Azure ARM - HttpsOnly for webapps

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-cli

I've tried the following azure command:

```
az webapp update --resource-group <YourResourceGroupName> --name <YourWebAppName> --set httpsOnly=true
```

However I got the following response:

> az: error: unrecognized arguments: --set httpsOnly=true

I'm running the command in the docker image [azuresdk/azure-cli-python](https://hub.docker.com/r/azuresdk/azure-cli-python/) version 2.0.23

EDIT:

My mistake: I was not running `az update` but `az deployment` (which btw should support the `httpsOnly` flag IMO).

Answer (score 1):

We should use this command to set `HttpsOnly` for Azure Web app.

```
az webapp update --resource-group <YourResourceGroupName> --name <YourWebAppName> --set HttpsOnly=true
```

I run this command in Azure cloud shell, that works for me:

[image]

[image]

Also we can check it via Azure portal:

[image]

Note:

The Azure CLI version is `2.0.23`, we can find the CLI 2.0 release [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/release-notes-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest), we can follow this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest) to install Azure CLI 2.0.